# How to cast an IplImage* to a cv:Mat*?

Tags: android, c, opencv

I´m a begginer on C Language and I need to copy pixels to Android Bitmap, I´m using a piece of code of android opencv, used for a jni:

```
AndroidBitmapInfo  info;
void*              pixels;
int                ret;
cv::Mat* mat;


if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info)) < 0 ){
    LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);

    return false; // can't get info
}

if (info.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888){
    LOGE("Bitmap format is not RGB_8888 !");
    return false; // incompatible format
}

if ( (ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels)) < 0 ){
    LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
    return false; // can't get pixels
}

memcpy(pixels, mat->data, info.height * info.width * 4);

AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
```

So, I have an IplImage* called pImage, but I don´t know how to convert an IplImage* to a cv::Mat*. I see a way to convert to a cv:Mat, like this:

```
cv::Mat mat(pImage);
```

But I need an cv:Mat* not an cv:Mat. Any help?

Comment: Just so you note, cv::Mat is not C but C++.

Comment: And what is your problem? You don't know how to get address of the cv::Mat object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to your question title:

```
cv::Mat* mat = new cv::Mat(pImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV tutorials include an article on [Interoperability with OpenCV 1](http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/doc/tutorials/core/interoperability_with_OpenCV_1/interoperability_with_OpenCV_1.html#interoperabilitywithopencv1).